# Question about codimension of a special variety.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

Let $G(k,n)$ denote Grassmannians. For a hypersurface $W\subset \mathbb{P}^n$ of degree $2$, we let $\tau(W)\subset G(2,n+1)$ denotes the set of lines in $\mathbb{P}^n$ lying on $W$. $\tau(W)$ is an analytic cycle in $G(2,n+1)$.

It's said that since a line $l\subset \mathbb{P}^n$ lies on $W$ if and only if three points of $l$ lie on $W$, $\tau(W)$ has complex codimension $3$. I don't know why this follows? Hope someone could help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear to me what's the reasoning of authors, but here is my approach:

Suppose $l$ is the line joining $[1,0,...,0]$ and $[0,1,0...,0]$ on $\mathbb P^n$. Let $F(z_0,z_1,...,z_n)$ be the quadric equation of $W$, which vanishes on $l$, so there is no $z_0^2,z_0z_1,z_2^2$ terms. Moreover, up to change of coordinate, we can write $$F(z_0,...,z_n)=z_0z_2+z_1z_3+\text{higher}\ \text{order}\ \text{terms}\ \text{in}\ z_2,...,z_n.\tag{1}\label{1}$$

On the other hand, there is affine coordinate $(x_2,..,x_{n},y_2,...,y_{n})$ on $G(2,n+1)$ corresponding to the line

$$l_{x,y}=\{s[1,0,x_2,...,x_{n}]+t[0,1,y_2,...,y_{n}],\ (s,t)\in \mathbb P^1\}\tag{2}\label{2}$$ with $x_i=y_j=0$ corrsponds to $l$.

Now by plugging $(\ref{2})$ into $(\ref{1})$, the condition $l_{x,y}\subseteq W$ translates to $$F(s,t,sx_2+ty_2,...,sx_{n}+ty_{n})\equiv 0$$

Expand the polynomial and set coefficients of $s^2,st,t^2$ equal to zero, we get
three equations

\begin{cases}
x_2+\text{higher}\ \text{powers}=0;\\
x_3+y_2+\text{higher}\ \text{powers}=0;\\
y_3+\text{higher}\ \text{powers}=0.
\end{cases}

That's the local equation of $\tau(W)$ in $G(2,n+1)$ around $l$. Since they have distinct linear terms, $\tau(W)$ is smooth of codimension three.

Comment: I am not sure about this. I don’t know whether every line of $\tau(W)$ can be written as the form $l_{x,y}$ you wrote. Besides, $s$ and $t$ should satisfy $s+t=1$. Maybe three points on $W$ means three equations, thus means $\tau(W)$ is of codimension $3$?

Comment: @YuyiZhang About $l_{x,y}$: it's an affine chart of $G(2,n+1)$, i.e., $\mathbb C^{2n-2}$. About $s$ and $t$: the line is projective line, not affine line, $(s,t)$ is in $\mathbb P^1$ (and $s+t=1$ does not make sense). About your last comment, the three points are not fixed points, it is a condition that will depend on the choice of line, how do you write down an equation? Maybe you can try the incidence relation with $W\times W\times W$.